# Why is insertion sort used along with merge sort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, mergesort, insertion-sort

I see in some explanations and some libraries, e.g. Java, in which below  a specified number of threshold elements Insertion Sort is used along with Merge Sort. Its reason is because Insertion Sort is stable as well. However, **Bubble Sort** or Tim Sort is also stable, of course there could be another sorts. I wonder why Insertion Sort is used in lieu of the others.

Comment: Since Tim Sort itself is a hybrid sorting algorithm that uses Insertion Sort for smaller sections, why do you think you'd want to use it as a replacement for Insertion Sort?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever actually I wonder _why not bubble sort_ instead of insertion sort?

Answer (score 1):

Insertion sort usually is a bit faster than other simple quadratic sort methods  - partially due to using of element chain shifting instead of full swapping.

And simple sorts in general faster for small subarrays than more complex methods like TimSort

Answer (score 1):

Obviously "because it is faster for small arrays".

The basic reason why it is faster is that there are huge penalties in the CPU for choices that the CPU can't predict the answer to.  Those are called pipeline stalls.  Insertion sort minimizes pipeline stalls.

Efficient sorts have lots of either/or questions that have even chances of turning out either way.  So, for example, half the comparisons in a quicksort will be predicted wrong.  So, for example, with 100 elements we expect to need around 650 comparisons (actually on average 647.85, see page 12 of http://ac.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/lak_teaching/ws08_09/average-case/average_case.pdf for the formula) of which on average half are predicted wrong for 325 pipeline stalls.

An insertion sort has a lot of predictions, but their outcome is very predictable - we haven't reached the insertion point yet.  With 100 elements we'll therefore average around 2500 comparisons, but only 99 of them will be pipeline stalls.  If a pipeline stall costs much more than 10 comparisons, that will make insertion sort faster.  Per https://gist.github.com/jboner/2841832 you can see that grabbing a number to compare is around .5 ns and a branch mispredict (aka pipeline stall) is around 5 ns, so the difference is about a factor of 10.  Which is why 100 elements is around the point where insertion sort becomes faster than quicksort in practice.

Bubble sort does not do well on this metric.  We both have a quadratic number of comparisons and a quadratic number of pipeline stalls.  But that shouldn't be a surprise.  The main purpose of bubble sort is to make a convenient punching bag because it is easy to code and sucks so badly.

Comment: 100? In my experience it's closer to 15 or 20. I guess it depends on hardware.

Comment: @JimMischel It depends on hardware and data type and luck of the draw.  The best case for insertion sort will be comparing small integers.  But if you've got small strings, insertion sort will do a lot worse.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100 % but if i Remember correct it has to do with the fact that insertion sort has atleast theoretically sqap less times then bubble sort.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting algorithms designers do benchmark alternative sorts for a small number of elements and integrate them as a bootstrap of the efficient ones.